# Archiving data from Table1 to Table2 upon condition | Sql Server 2017 Express

Tags: sql-server, archive, auto-update

I have a database with two tables:

Table `Student` with the following
columns:

```
StudentID int identity, 
StudentFN, 
StudentLN, 
Active bit, 
EnrollmentDate
```

Table `ArchivedStudent` with the following columns:

```
ArvchivedStudentID int identity, 
StudentID int, 
StudentFN, 
StudentLN, 
WithdrawalDate getdate(), 
ReasonDropped
```

In the long run, I'd like to schedule automatic updates for the table `AcrchivedStudent` and move the data from columns `StudentID, StudentFN` and `StudentLN` from table Student to table `ArchnivedStudent` when column Active changes from 1 (true) to 0 (false).

Here's my start up script that is not working:

```
update [as]
set [as].StudentID = s.StudentID,
 [as].StudentFN = s.StudentFN,
 [as].StudentLN = s.StudentLN
from ArchivedStudent [as]

 inner join Student s
on [as].StudentID = s.StudentID
where s.Active = 0

go
```

The issue is that it does not return any results.

Once I'll be able to update table `ArchivedStudent`, I'd like to delete data of the students whose Active status changed to 0 in the Student table.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's currently unclear what technologies you use and what you need help with. Please clarify that using the tags section and we will be happy to help you. Also, have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: Any help, please?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, it is still unclear what you're asking exactly. If you want us to write the code for you, you will likely get no answer. If that's not the case, please describe the efforts you have done so far and the issues you are facing. Cheers :-)

Comment: Oh sorry. The startup code is not working (not returning any results):
update [as]
set [as].StudentID = s.StudentID,
 [as].StudentFN = s.StudentFN,
 [as].StudentLN = s.StudentLN
from ArchivedStudent [as]

 inner join Student s
on [as].StudentID = s.StudentID
where s.Active = 0

go

Comment: I just edited your question so that it's clear for everybody (my edit is still in the review queue so give it a little time to show up). Unfortunately, I also saw your question in the review queue and personally have no idea about sql server. I thus gave the question a little bounty so that it will show up on the front page and hopefully get more attention. Happy coding :)

Comment: You can use a trigger to add a student to the archive and delete the respective row in the students table every time an active status changes to 0. But how do you want to fill the "ReasonDropped" column?

Comment: Hey @Zino cosider marking the answer that worked for you as the solution (the green tick), that way, the bounty is awarded to the author of the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question still isn't very clear on the process. For example, do you want to allow the student to be deactivated for a certain period of time before they are moved to the archive table or do you want the student to be immediately moved to the archived table once the student is deactivated?

If the latter, this is much easier:

```
INSERT INTO ArchivedStudent (StudentId, StudentFn, StudentLn, WithdrawalDate)
SELECT S.StudentId, S.StudentFn, S.StudentLn, GETDATE()
FROM Student S
WHERE StudentId = ?

DELETE FROM Student WHERE StudentId = ?
```

If the former, then that is more challenging and we will require more detail.

**Update 1:**

To set the Withdrawal date based off a calculated value, use the following:

```
INSERT INTO ArchivedStudent (StudentId, StudentFn, StudentLn, WithdrawalDate)
SELECT S.StudentId, S.StudentFn, S.StudentLn, CAST(DATEADD(D,14,GETDATE()) AS DATE)
FROM Student S
WHERE StudentId = ?
```

Note 1: In DATEADD(), use a positive value for future dates and use a negative value for past dates. You can remove the DATE CAST if you need the actual time in addition to the date.

Note 2: The DELETE script posted in the original answer still stands.

Comment: If this is the answer, will you please mark it as answered?

Comment: Yes! I want to move the student to the archived table immediately once their status changes to non-active.

Comment: Does the date need to be a known, static, value or a calculated value?

Comment: Hi, what if instead of getdate(), I'd like a calculated value of the date 2 weeks from today?

Answer (score 1):

You need a trigger to do it :

```
CREATE TRIGGER ArchiveStudent ON Student 
   FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO ArchivedStudent (StudentID, StudentFN, StudentLN)
    SELECT 
        StudentID
    ,   StudentFN
    ,   StudentLN
    FROM 
        Student 
    WHERE 
        Active = 0


    DELETE FROM Student
    WHERE 
        Active = 0  
END
```

However, your approach it's simple, and risky at the same time. For instance, if someone made a student inactive by mistake, then the trigger will immediately insert that student into archive table then deleted. Surely you can retrieve it by many ways such as deleted, inserted tables or even get the max id of archive table, but why you put yourself in this situation in the first place?. This is one of many general issues could be experienced by the current approach. A better approach is to actually add more versioning or historian methods for the tables, and make the archives run either from SQL Job or a store procedure on a fixed dates rather than triggers. this would give you a scheduled and controlled data archiving.

You can even add a historian columns which will store the value of active column and the date of the change. Then, use trigger or store procedure to do it for you (or even a computed column with a generic scalar function that will be reused on multiple tables). for instance, if the student is inactive for 5 business days, then archive it and delete it from the table.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE on the Student table.

This trigger would:
 - react only on UPDATE,
 - transfer Student to ArchiveStudent, when Active is set to 0
 - and set WithdrawalDate to 2 weeks from today.

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Student_Changed] 
   ON  Student
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- Archive
    INSERT INTO ArchiveStudent
        (StudentID, StudentFN, StudentLN, WithdrawalDate)
    SELECT
        DELETED.StudentID
        ,DELETED.[StudentFN]
        ,DELETED.[StudentLN]
        ,DATEADD(day, 14, GETDATE()) -- 2 Weeks from today
    FROM DELETED
    WHERE DELETED.Active = 1

    -- Delete archived
    DELETE FROM Student
    WHERE StudentID = (SELECT DELETED.[StudentID] FROM DELETED)
        AND Active = 0
END;
```

**DEMO:**

You can take a look at the SQL Fiddle solution [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f28e9/1).

Comment: @Zino - modified to show value of the date 2 weeks from today, as per your request

Comment: @Zino - If any of these were helpfull, please mark them as answer. Otherwise, note what should be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions here that all appear partially correct, but with some issues. Your initial update of your archive table will not insert into the archive table, only update an existing row. And since you are trying to join between the live table and the archive table, you will get no results - well, no updates since an update statement doesn't produce "results" as such anyway.

So as other have said you would use two statements - one an insert statement and one a delete. I would tend to be on the careful side and make sure that I a) dont get duplicates in my archive table and b) dont delete from live before I am sure its made it into the archive. So the two statements would be:

```
insert archivestudent(...fieldlist...)
select * from student 
where active=0
and not exists(select * from archivestudent where archivestudent.studentid=student.studentid)

delete student 
where active=0 
and exists(select * from archivestudent where archivedstudent.studentid=student.studentid)
```

You can then run this code whenever you wish, schedule it as a job to run each night, whatever makes sense in your app.

If, on the other hand you want to immediately run then a trigger is the way to go. Be aware though that triggers are set-based operations, meaning that the trigger runs once for all rows affected by an update. This means that the solution proposed by @Milan will fail if the triggering update affects more than one row, because the clause `WHERE StudentID = (SELECT DELETED.[StudentID] FROM DELETED)` will return more one value. An example might be `update student set active=0 where enrolmentdate<'2017-01-01'`

You should always join to the internal tables exposed inside a trigger, in this case the DELETED table

```
delete student
from deleted
join student on student.studentid=deleted.studentid
where active=0
```

I'd still be tempted to add the where exists/not exists clauses inside the trigger as well just to make it more error-proof.

Answer (score 0):

You need two queries:

Insert

```
Insert into archivedstudent (studentid, student, studentln) select studentid, studentfn, studentln from student where active=0 and studentid not in (select studentid from archivedstudent);
```

And the delete

```
Delete from student  where studentid in (select studentid from archivedstudent);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a trigger.[SQL Server Trigger After Update for a Specific Value](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4024/sql-server-trigger-after-update-for-a-specific-value/) However you should be careful with triggers on large amounts of data, they can hurt performance.